# Why does my context consumer not automatically update?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I am working on a react native app and I have an array of components that I need to be updated from different sections of my app. I am using context to be able to provide different consumers with this array, as well as the ability to the update the array.

As you can see in the code below I am passing my array, as well as a function to update the list, as the value for my provider. I then am using "header-right" in the navigation to call the function that updates the array in the provider state. I have confirmed that the array is updating and will only re-render the consumers when a change state in another component causes a re-render.

What I need is the change state of the provider to re-render all consumer components when it is changed, not when another components state change has occurred.

```
const DbContext = React.createContext("DEFAULT");

export default class DbProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        choreList: [],
        refresh:null,
      }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      sqlQueries.getChores().then(row => this.setChoresList(row));
    }

    updateChoreList = (choresAdded, offset) => {
      console.log("K");

      if(offset == 1){ // if adding chores
        var tempList = this.state.choreList;
        tempList.push(choresAdded);
        this.setState({
          choreList: tempList,
        })
      }else if(offset == -1){ // if removing a chore
        for(var i = 0; i < this.state.choreList.length; i++){ 
          for(var j = 0; j < choresAdded.length; j++){ 
            if(this.state.choreList[i].state.name == choresAdded[i].state.name){ // if chore being removed is i in state choreList
              var tempList = this.state.choreList; // remove and update state choreList
              tempList.splice(i, 1);
              this.setState({
                choreList: tempList,
              });
              break;
            }
          }
          }
        }
    }

    setChoresList(row){
      var tempList = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < row._array.length; i++){
          tempList.push(<Chore choreName={row._array[i].name} dayId={row._array[i].id} nav={this.props} inDB={true} key={row._array[i].name}/>);
      }
  
      this.setState({
        choreList: tempList,
      })
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <DbContext.Provider value={{choreList: this.state.choreList, update: this.updateChoreList}}>
          {this.props.children}
        </DbContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }

  
  
  export { DbContext, DbProvider }
```

I am then in another component using this list to display something

```
 render(){
        return ( 
          <DbProvider>
            <DbContext.Consumer>
              {globalChores => globalChores.choreList == 0
              ? <NoChores nav={this.props.nav} dayState={this} />
              : ( 
              <View style={styles.ChoreDayContainer}>
                <View style={styles.ChoreListContainer}>
                {globalChores.choreList}
                </View>
                <AddChoresBtn nav={this.props.nav} dayState={this}/>
              </View>)}
            </DbContext.Consumer>
          </DbProvider>            
        );
      }
```

and finally I am updating the provided array like so

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <DbProvider>
        <DbContext.Consumer>{(db) =>(
          <Button
            onPress={ () => this.dataToDB(db)}
            title="Save"
            color="#fff"
          />          )}
          </DbContext.Consumer></DbProvider>
              ),
    })

  }

  dataToDB(db){

      db.update(this.state.choreShowingList, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Inside your context file, you have added `export default class DbProvider`, but at the end you've also added `export { DbContext, DbProvider }`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, however it didn't fix the issue. The consumers are still not automatically updating.